# PHP Mysql select from variable problem

Tags: php, mysql, reserved-words

I have tried so many different soloutions but cannot get this to work
Here is my code:

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
$query = "SELECT to FROM to WHERE to='$to' " 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

I get a whole load of different errors every time i modify it. At the moment I'm getting

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near to='Name'
```

When I modify it to fix this I get

```
mysql_fetch_array() not valid
```

It seems when using variables it messes up

can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the column is named 'to', and the table is named 'to' too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to` is a [reserved word in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

You would have to wrap each mention of the table or column name into backticks

```
SELECT `to` from `to`
```

but it would be vastly better to use a different name.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have mostly solved it.
But
i now have this code

$usersent = $_POST['usersent'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE usersent='$usersent' ";
 
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

and if i enter usersent='TheName' ";
it all works find
but when using the variable i dont get a response, i type in TheName on my html but it comes up no results

Answer (score 3):

To is a Reserved keyword try escaping it by using "``" symbol

Check this Link

[Reserved Keywords MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing the names of your field and table (Edit: Definitely change the names or at least escape them.) Also, all you are doing is selecting the variable you already have.